# What happened to my Push Notification service instance on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I made a Push Notification service instance two weeks ago, and now I can't find it. There is a new UI, and I can't find where my old service is located.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Bluemix Mobile** tab has recently been updated with a new dashboard, and now the user is greeted with a Mobile Projects page.

You can find your old service instances by clicking the **Services** tab at the top of the page.

**Mobile Projects:**
[image: projects]

Click the **Services** tab.

**Mobile Services:**
[image: services]